# Removing Spacing in Chapter Environments in LyX 2.3

Tags: lyx, environments, chapters

I am beginning to write a thesis in LyX as I find it easier to use for writing longer documents. I am using the "Report (Standard Class with Extra Font Sizes)" document class and I'm wondering if there's a way to remove/cut down on the whitespace between Chapter Marker, Chapter Title, and the text of the chapter from within LyX itself. Below is an image of the PDF export of my document for reference. [image]

Comment: you presumably have `\flushbottom` in effect and some large non floating thing at the top of the next page, what you show is not the intended layout but an over-stretched page as tex is trying to make the last line of text be at the bottom of the page. basically don't worry about it until you have almost finished your thesis, the page breaks will adjust as the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by using Page Breaks to separate the start of each chapter. Using New Pages has fixed this issue entirely.

Comment: Please accept this answer to mark the question as solved.